# Wrote a Custom Eslint Plugin to automatically convert dot operators (.) to optional chain operators (?.)

Tags: eslint-plugin

I write a eslint plugin, but when I use it in my react project,it does not work, I really have no ideal what's wrong with it.
here is the code :

```
const ruleComposer = require("eslint-rule-composer");

const convertDotToOptionalChain = ruleComposer.filterReports(
    (context) => true, // check all code
    (context) => {
        const sourceCode = context.getSourceCode();
        let insideObjectAccess = false; // Track if we are inside an object access context

        return {
            MemberExpression(node) {
                const tokens = sourceCode.getTokens(node);
                const dotToken = tokens.at(-2);

                if (dotToken.value === "?.") {
                    // Already an optional chain, skip
                    return;
                }

                if (insideObjectAccess) {
                    context.report({
                        node,
                        loc: tokens.at(-2).loc,
                        message: "should use optional chain",
                        fix: (fixer) => {
                            return fixer.insertTextBefore(dotToken, "?");
                        },
                    });
                }
            },
            "MemberExpression:exit"(node) {
                // Reset insideObjectAccess when exiting MemberExpression
                const tokens = sourceCode.getTokens(node);
                const dotToken = tokens.at(-2);
                if (dotToken.value === ".") {
                    insideObjectAccess = false;
                }
            },
            ObjectExpression() {
                // We are inside an object context
                insideObjectAccess = true;
            },
        };
    }
);

module.exports = {
    rules: {
        "auto-optional-chain": convertDotToOptionalChain,
    },
};
```

this is the repository:
https://github.com/Torres7707/eslint-plugin-auto-optional-chain

I try to use it in the react app ,but it does not work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.